# contains any characters mysql full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Hi all i am using my sql full text search to get result.

i wrote following query.

```
 SELECT detail FROM t_subcategor1y
    WHERE MATCH (detail) AGAINST ('hakti*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) or detail Like 'hakti%';
```

Here is my table in image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FROdm.png)
i am not getting any result  in query. so please any one can tell me where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: `'*hakti*'` and `'%hakti%`